# How do I automatically turn a page and crawl more data on Stack Overflow (Python)?

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, web-crawler

I want to crawl the **questions/answers URLs** on Stack Overflow with the Android Studio tag for research purposes. There should be around 55,628 questions on the site:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android-studio?sort=newest&page=1&pagesize=15

> However, I can only crawl 50 questions by far. It ends crawling in the middle of the forth page

I feel like I should write a **for loop** to iterate the URL, but I cannot picture where to revise first.
How do revise my program?

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re
import json

class Stack(object):

    def __init__(self):
        self.baseurl = "https://stackoverflow.com"
        self.starturl = "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android-studio"

        # The second page's URL: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android-studio?sort=newest&page=2&pagesize=15
        # The third page's URL: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android-studio?sort=newest&page=3&pagesize=15


    def start_requests(self, url):
        r = requests.get(url)
        return r.content


    def parse(self, text):
        soup = BeautifulSoup(text, 'html.parser')
        divs = soup.find_all('div', class_ = 'question-summary')

        for div in divs:
            div.find('div', class_ = 'summary').find_all('div')[1].find_all('a')


            yield {
            'title': div.h3.a.text,
            'url': self.baseurl + div.h3.a.get('href')
            }


    def start(self):
        text = self.start_requests(self.starturl) #呼叫function start_requests
        items = self.parse(text)

        s = json.dumps(list(items), indent = 4, ensure_ascii=False)
        with open('stackoverflow.json', 'w', encoding = 'utf-8') as f:
            # If answer is nonempty
            f.write(s)

stack = Stack()
stack.start()
```

Comment: Can you get what you need via api? https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/authentication

Comment: unrelated but change the page size argument in the url to 50 to reduce the loop